# Why wifi and ethernet use the same frame format from tcpdump -d output?

Tags: ethernet, ieee-802.11, tcpdump

If I execute

```
tcpdump -i wlan0 tcp -d
```

or

```
tcpdump -i eth0 tcp -d
```

I get the same output

```
(000) ldh      [12]
(001) jeq      #0x86dd          jt 2    jf 7
(002) ldb      [20]
(003) jeq      #0x6             jt 10   jf 4
(004) jeq      #0x2c            jt 5    jf 11
(005) ldb      [54]
(006) jeq      #0x6             jt 10   jf 11
(007) jeq      #0x800           jt 8    jf 11
(008) ldb      [23]
(009) jeq      #0x6             jt 10   jf 11
(010) ret      #262144
(011) ret      #0
```

So both check the field type of an ethernet IEEE 802.3 header. I'd expected another kind of offset for wifi interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relation between Ethernet and 802.11 headers](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35618/relation-between-ethernet-and-802-11-headers)

Comment: Many (most) Wifi drivers present the interface as Ethernet to the operating system.  You need a driver that can be put into "monitor" mode.